# Merging two objects in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I have two objects of same type.

```
Class A {
  String a;
  List b;
  int c;
}

A obj1 = new A();
A obj2 = new A();

obj1 => {a = "hello"; b = null; c = 10}
obj2 => {a = null; b = new ArrayList(); c = default value}
```

Can you please let me know what is the best way to combine this objects into single object?

```
obj3 = {a = "hello"; b = (same arraylist from obj2); c = 10}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you expect this single "merged" object to look like?

Comment: If `obj1.a = "George"` and `obj2.a = "Lucas"` what should the value of `obj3.a` in the "merged" object be?

Comment: You can assume the objects are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
class A {
    String a;
    List<..> b;
    int c;

    public void merge(A other) {
        this.a = other.a == null ? this.a : other.a;
        this.b.addAll(other.b);
        this.c = other.c == 0 ? this.c : other.c;
    }
}

A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();

a1.a = "a prop";
a2.c = 34;

a1.merge(a2);
```

`A.merge` might return a new `A` object instead of modifing current.

Comment: That's what I was going to recommend--you have to clearly codify the rules somewhere anyway--you don't want to add "Magic" like reflection to your code unless it's absolutely the last resort--and this case is by no means that difficult.

Comment: NullPointerException since `this.b` might be `null`, and it is not fulfilling the "same arraylist from obj2" request for `b`

Answer (score 31):

This works as long as you have POJOs with their own getters and setters. The method updates **obj** with non-null values from **update**. It calls setParameter() on **obj** with the return value of getParameter() on **update**:

```
public void merge(Object obj, Object update){
    if(!obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(update.getClass())){
        return;
    }

    Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();

    for(Method fromMethod: methods){
        if(fromMethod.getDeclaringClass().equals(obj.getClass())
                && fromMethod.getName().startsWith("get")){

            String fromName = fromMethod.getName();
            String toName = fromName.replace("get", "set");

            try {
                Method toMetod = obj.getClass().getMethod(toName, fromMethod.getReturnType());
                Object value = fromMethod.invoke(update, (Object[])null);
                if(value != null){
                    toMetod.invoke(obj, value);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But my object have a lot of primitive types like int,float e.t.c. It also has List as members.

Comment: Nevermind. As long as both object have getXX and its corresponding setXX, this will work. It will copy just values with a getter AND a setter

Comment: Use obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods() to skip getClass/setClass etc and get methods defined in that class or corresponding interface only.

Comment: I am confused by the first if. what is that trying to achieve?

Comment: isn't it supposed to return an object...?

Comment: @jon The function _updates_ the `obj` parameter object so all changes are saved to the `obj` instance instead of returning an updated object. You could return `obj` at the end of the function, but it will be unnecessary.

Comment: `String toName = fromName.replace("get", "set");`
what happen if I have a field have name `thisisfieldsetted`?

Comment: In general, this code is hard to understand at a glance. There's got to be a better way to write this. As such I'm a fan of Zon's answer below.

Comment: @HuyTTQ you can use `String toName = fromName.replaceFirst("get", "set");`. Since the if condition asserts the method starts with `"get"`, only the beginning `get` will be replaced.

Answer (score 22):

I am using Spring Framework. I was facing the same issue on a project.
To solve it i used the class [BeanUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html) and the above method,

```
public static void copyProperties(Object source, Object target)
```

This is an example,

```
public class Model1 {
    private String propertyA;
    private String propertyB;

    public Model1() {
        this.propertyA = "";
        this.propertyB = "";
    }

    public String getPropertyA() {
        return this.propertyA;
    }

    public void setPropertyA(String propertyA) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
    }

    public String getPropertyB() {
        return this.propertyB;
    }

    public void setPropertyB(String propertyB) {
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }
}

public class Model2 {
    private String propertyA;

    public Model2() {
        this.propertyA = "";
    }

    public String getPropertyA() {
        return this.propertyA;
    }

    public void setPropertyA(String propertyA) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
    }
}

public class JustATest {

    public void makeATest() {
        // Initalize one model per class.
        Model1 model1 = new Model1();
        model1.setPropertyA("1a");
        model1.setPropertyB("1b");

        Model2 model2 = new Model2();
        model2.setPropertyA("2a");

        // Merge properties using BeanUtils class.
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(model2, model1);

        // The output.
        System.out.println("Model1.propertyA:" + model1.getPropertyA(); //=> 2a
        System.out.println("Model1.propertyB:" + model1.getPropertyB(); //=> 1b
    }
}
```

Comment: `BeanUtils.copyProperties` does not check if copied over properties have `null` and ignore them.

Answer (score 7):

Just accommodating boolean sync. and case sensitive(camel notation)

```
public boolean merge(Object obj){

    if(this.equals(obj)){
        return false;
    }

    if(!obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(this.getClass())){
        return false;
    }

    Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();

    for(Method fromMethod: methods){
        if(fromMethod.getDeclaringClass().equals(obj.getClass())
                && (fromMethod.getName().matches("^get[A-Z].*$")||fromMethod.getName().matches("^is[A-Z].*$"))){

            String fromName = fromMethod.getName();
            String toName ;
            if(fromName.matches("^get[A-Z].*")){
                toName = fromName.replace("get", "set");
            }else{
                toName = fromName.replace("is", "set");
            }

            try {
                Method toMetod = obj.getClass().getMethod(toName, fromMethod.getReturnType());
                Object value = fromMethod.invoke(this, (Object[])null);
                if(value != null){
                    toMetod.invoke(obj, value);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you create getters and setters for the attributes, you can use the [copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method from Commons BeanUtils.

Answer (score 5):

Add this **method to your POJO**, then use it like `myObject.merge(newObject)`. It uses generics to loop through your POJO's fields, so you **don't mention any field names**:

```
/**
 * Fill current object fields with new object values, ignoring new NULLs. Old values are overwritten.
 *
 * @param newObject Same type object with new values.
 */
public void merge(Object newObject) {

  assert this.getClass().getName().equals(newObject.getClass().getName());

  for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

    for (Field newField : newObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

      if (field.getName().equals(newField.getName())) {

        try {

          field.set(
              this,
              newField.get(newObject) == null
                  ? field.get(this)
                  : newField.get(newObject));

        } catch (IllegalAccessException ignore) {
          // Field update exception on final modifier and other cases.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the BEST solution if you don't want to constantly maintain the method when adding/removing fields etc.

I'd go a step further and NOT ignore "IllegalAccessException" as it might hide problems, but instead have alternative cases for specific fields you don't want to merge - or you want to handle differently etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is a dynamic solution to merge any two objects which require Reflection and Recursion.

```
public <T> T merge(T local, T remote, ArrayList<String> listOfClass)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class<?> clazz = local.getClass();
    Object merged = clazz.newInstance();
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object localValue = field.get(local);
        Object remoteValue = field.get(remote);
        if (localValue != null) {
            if (listOfClass.contains(localValue.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                field.set(merged, this.merge(localValue, remoteValue, listOfClass));
            } else {
                field.set(merged, (remoteValue != null) ? remoteValue : localValue);
            }
        } else if (remoteValue != null) {
            field.set(merged, remoteValue);
        }
    }
    return (T) merged;
}
```

Variable Description:

- local: The object on to which the other will be merged
- remote: The object which will be merged to the local object
- listOfClass: The ArrayList of custom classes in the given object

The function returns a merged object which is good to go.

Kudos! :)

Answer (score 2):

In your very special case it looks like you want a new object that takes the *real* values from both instances. Here is an implementation that will do that. The method should be add to class `A` so that it can access the fields.

```
 public A specialMergeWith(A other) {
   A result = new A();

   result.a = (a == null ? other.a : a);
   result.b = (b == null ? other.b : b);
   result.c = (c == DEFAULT_VALUE ? other.c : c);

   return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Object mergeObjects(Object source, Object target) throws Exception {
        Field[] allFields = source.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : allFields) {
            if(Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())){
                continue;
            }

            if (!field.isAccessible() && Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()))
                field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(source) != null) {
                field.set(target, field.get(source));
            }
        }

        return target;
    }
```

Using java reflection, support only for the same class.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T mergeObjects(T first, T second) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
       Class<?> clazz = first.getClass();
       Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
       Object returnValue = clazz.newInstance();
       for (Field field : fields) {
          field.setAccessible(true);
          Object value1 = field.get(first);
          Object value2 = field.get(second);
          if( value1.getClass().isPrimitive()){
             Object value = (value2 != null) ? value2 : value1;
             field.set(returnValue, value);
          }
          mergeObjects(value1, value2);  
       }
       return (T) returnValue;
    }
```