# Spring REST controller partial update existing resource

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to perform a partial update for a resource. I had an idea that I could combine @ModelAttribute (to load the existing resource) and @RequestBody to populate it with the provided fields and then run @Valid. As I understand @ModelAttribute is invoked before anything else.

My Controller invokes the ModelAttribut and is using my ContentPatternConverter to create the ContentPattern entity correctly. Though after that is done I want to populate the "pattern" with the provided fields from @RequestBody and finally check if it is valid. Though my the ContentPattern is not populated with RequestBody after it was created via ModelAttribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patterns/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ContentPattern> updateContentPattern(Principal principal, @ModelAttribute("id") @RequestBody ContentPattern pattern) { //implementation }
```

Any ideas how to solve this using my approach or if there is another (better) solution?

**UPDATE 1**

After some more researching I came up with following solution.

1. Created my own annotation @RequestBodyPathVariable
2. Wrote RequestBodyPathVariableMethodArgumentResolver which implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. What it does is 1) Based on the URI path variable (e.g. patterns/{id}) gets the existing resource from a custom converter. 2) Creates an object from the request body. 3) Merges the existing and the provided resource. 4) Validates the final object. 5) Returns the final object

See gist for source code: https://gist.github.com/2687913

(A better/other merge method might be needed for other cases.)

Helpful links:
http://blog.42.nl/articles/leveraging-the-spring-mvc-3.1-handlermethodargumentresolver-interface
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591665/merging-two-objects-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this, and here is what I would do (disclaimer, I haven't tried this):

First of all, [@ModelAttribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) will only serve if you want to pass that object to the view.

[@RequestBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) allows Spring to parse your input body (let's say it's Json) and build a ContentPattern object. But you want to get that object from your repository and then update the relevant fields.

First, I would create an implementation of [WebArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html). Using [MethodParameter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html) you check that it is from class ContentPattern. This implementation will receive as Dependency Injection, the [HttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) you use to create the ContentPattern object.

Then you create a [HttpInputMessage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpInputMessage.html) from the [NativeWebRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/NativeWebRequest.html), like this:

```
return new ServletServerHttpRequest((HttpServletRequest)nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest());
```

Then using the Converter, you create your ContentPattern object. This object will have some fields populated, the ones you want to update, and also its identifier.

Using the identifier, and your repository, or an [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/) persistence context (both injected to the class by Spring), you get the object from your repository.

Now you have two ContentPattern objects, the one obtained from the repository, and the one created from the request body.

Using your object's setters, update the object from the repository with the fields of the other object, and then validate it using your [Validator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/) also injected to this class by Spring.

If everything is ok, optionally save the updated object to persistance, and use it as the returning value of the [resolverArgument](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html#resolveArgument%28org.springframework.core.MethodParameter,%20org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest%29) method.

I hope this is clear enough!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I ended up using the same concept but implemented HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.